# How to increase Textbox border thickness in WPF

Tags: c#

Trying to find a way to increase the thickness of a textbox border without using XAML. Searched everywhere on the site, but I think I'm missing something. I would think this would be rather simple. I have never used XAML, so trying to avoid it if I can to get this complete.

Comment: Welcome!  Your question is kinda open-ended sounding like you want us to write code for you. [ask].  Anyway, you can do this purely from C# code without a need for looking at XAML.  Take a look at `Border`.   Just plonk your `Textbox` inside one

Comment: Sorry, I should know better. A site would help, no need for written code.I will check out the Border API.

Comment: Seriously was making that harder than it needed to be. Thanks MickyD!

Comment: Not a problem good sir.  Happy WPF'ing

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just do

```
textbox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3,3,3,3);
```

Voila!